# ray.tune with reuse_actors=True doesn't call reset_config

Tags: ray

ray v1.0.0, python 3.7, running ray locally for the below experiment.

Following the documentation at:

https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/api_docs/trainable.html?highlight=reuse%20actors#advanced-reusing-actors

I'm using the `Trainable` class API and I implement the `reset_config` method. Then, I set `reuse_actors=True` in `tune.run` and make sure that the trials are executed sequentially so that reusing actors is possible. All the trials run but the `reset_config` method is never called.

Are there any conflicts between `reuse_actors` and other `tune.run` and/or `tune.experiment` arguments?